# Spark - reading CSV file and enforcing Serial mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

All,

I am processing the vendor data files and adding few additional fields ( ENRICHMENT )
and requirement is that I always need to maintain the order of files.

Hence to achieve above, I am adding sequence ID using monotonically_increasing_id();
How can I ensure this operation is executed with partition = 1, so that ID is not repeated..
I am open to alternate suggestions.

```
    val srcDF = spark.read.textFile(PATH).withColumn("idCol", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`monotonically_increasing_id`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894877/spark-monotonically-increasing-id-not-working-as-expected-in-dataframe) use **`row_number`** window function.

- Use `spark.read.csv` if you are reading a delimited file.

**`Example:`**

```
//sample data

$cat t1.txt
NAME|AGE|COUNTRY
d|18|USA
a|18|USA
b|20|Germany
c|23|USA
```

---

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w=Window.orderBy("NAME")

spark.
read.
option("header",true).
option("delimiter","|").
csv("t1.txt").
withColumn("idCol",row_number().over(w)).
show()

//+----+---+-------+-----+
//|NAME|AGE|COUNTRY|idCol|
//+----+---+-------+-----+
//|   a| 18|    USA|    1|
//|   b| 20|Germany|    2|
//|   c| 23|    USA|    3|
//|   d| 18|    USA|    4|
//+----+---+-------+-----+
```

We are ordering by `NAME` column and then adding `idCol` will be assigned to all the rows with out repetition.

In addition if there is no orderby column then try:

```
val w=Window.orderBy(lit("1"))

spark.
read.
option("header",true).
option("delimiter","|").
csv("t1.txt").
withColumn("idCol",row_number().over(w)).
show()

//+----+---+-------+-----+
//|NAME|AGE|COUNTRY|idCol|
//+----+---+-------+-----+
//|   d| 18|    USA|    1|
//|   a| 18|    USA|    2|
//|   b| 20|Germany|    3|
//|   c| 23|    USA|    4|
//+----+---+-------+-----+
```