# Add column from one dataframe to another WITHOUT JOIN

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, join, pyspark

Referring to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028442/add-column-from-one-dataframe-to-another-dataframe-in-scala?rq=1) who recommends Join to append column from one table to another. I have been using this method indeed, but now reach some limitation for huge list of tables and rows

Let's say I have a dataframe of M features `id, salary, age, etc.`

```
+----+--------+------------+--------------+
| id | salary | age | zone |  ....  
+----+--------+------------+--------------+
```

I have perform certain operations on each feature to arrive at something like this

```
+----+--------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | salary | bin_salary | start_salary | end_salary | count_salary | stat1_salary | stat2_slaary | 
+----+--------+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Each feature is processed independently, with the **same list of rows**

```
+----+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
| id | salary | stat1_salary | stat2_salary | stat3_salary|
+----+--------+------------+--------------+------------+
| 301  | x1     | x          | x            | x |
| 302  | null   | x          | x            | x |
| 303  | x3     | x          | x            | x |

+----+--------+------------+--------------+
| id | age | stat1_age | stat2_age 
+----+--------+------------+--------------+
| 301  | null   | x          | x   
| 302  | x2     | x          | x   
| 303  | x3     | x          | x
```

In the end, I would like to combine them into the final dataframe with all attributes of each features, by joining on unique ID of effectively hundreds to thousand of table, each for one feature. This final dataframe is my feature vector

```
| id | salary | stat1_salary | stat2_salary | stat3_salary| age | stat1_age | stat2_age
```

I am hitting some Memory limit that cause `Out Of Memory` exception. Raising executor and driver memory seems to only be a temporary solution, and limited by admin.

JOIN is expensive and limited by resource in pyspark, and I wonder if it's possible to **pre-sort** each feature table independently, then **keep that order** and just **APPEND** the entire column next to one another instead of performing expensive JOIN. I can manage to keep all the same list of rows for each feature table. I hope to have no join nor lookup because my set of Id is the same.

How is it achievable ? As far as I understand, even if I sort each table by Id, Spark distribute them for storage and the retrieval (if I want to query back to append) does not guarantee to have that same order.

Comment: Your question piqued my curiosity. Are you talking about such an arrangement - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164274/efficient-way-of-joining-multiple-tables-in-spark

Comment: Indeed. But I have bigger problem with more features. Imagine each feature spawns a small attribute table with 10 columns, in the end joining them together create 10xhundreds of columns. That hurts. I am having either StackOverFlow or OutOfMemory issue now. I can support only up to certain number of features before crashing.

Comment: I am also being limited by the administrator and can’t really figure out a way from this maze. If you are able to solve this, do compose an answer.

Comment: Please could you clarify how the data is stored beforehand? It sounds like you have M tables of N columns (where a table is e.g. the salary table, and has a bunch of columns related to salary)? What's the format of the input data (e.g, JSON, Parquet..)?

Comment: Hi @Kenny all the datasets have the same schema? The first thing I would think is to use union.

Comment: Data is in Hadoop tabular format. Original table has M features salary, age,region,zone, etc. Each feature is put through some process in pyspark (not necessarily the same, for example categorical feature does not have start/end),  to spawn a table of attributes as example for salary; _independently_, to avoid modifying the huge table around one column each. I keep unique Id for final join in the end to string together all _attributes_ of all features. Desired output is Id/salary/attributes_for_salary/age/attributes_for_age/... as feature vector. No Union here because column-wise, not row-wise

Comment: This seems to be straightforward joins on a shared key. Problems are likely tied to indexing/ordering. Please give a [mcve]. Please clarify via edits, not comments Please do not link to anything necessary, put whatever is necessary (paraphrase/summary and/or quotes) in your post--make it self-contained. PS Generally speaking with tables it is a bad idea to put data into column names. That should be done as a last step for display. Eg we may want to display like with a matrix with 2 axes & a value at (row, column) but relational manipulation is per a table with columns (row, column, value).

Comment: The reproducible will not be possible because it depends on your particular system config. I suppose you haven't run into this problem. Could you elaborate on your last phrase about 2 axes and 3 axes ?

Comment: Hello Kenny, did you manage to solve this one without join?

Comment: Hi Alex, it seems we could not get away without Join. It boils down to optimizing the Join and try to limit the features list as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a spark function to append a column from one DF to another directly except 'join'.

If you are starting from only one dataframe and trying to generate new features from each original column of the dataframe.
I would suggest to use 'pandas_udf', where the new features can be appended in the 'udf' for all the original columns.

This will avoid using 'join' at all.
To control the memory usage, choose the 'group' column where we make sure that each group is within executor memory specification.